# Are Cassandra triggers Asynchronous?

Tags: cassandra

I am testing cassandra trigger and implemented the `ITrigger` interface.
As on the ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1311
it seems cassandra trigger should be async, means after a client made an insert, client should not wait for the trigger to be executed.

But I have added a sleep like 15 seconds in the Trigger and insert operation failed because of timeout. So it seems it is waiting the trigger finishes its job.

Is there a way to make trigger to work asynch?
(it should be already async according to pages I have read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, By default Cassandra wait for trigger execution.**

But you can change that using execute query with `QueryProcessor` and run into separate thread. Note that if you do this and trigger execution failed you will not be able to know that the trigger query failed from your main query.

Example for Cassandra 2.x :

```
@Override
public Collection<Mutation> augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily update) {
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //build your own query from the ByteBuffer key and ColumnFamily  update
            Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("test_keyspace.test_table").value("id", 1).value("data", "Test");

            //execute query  
            QueryProcessor.process(insert.toString(), ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);
        }
    }).start();
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ashraful, I am learning triggers in cassandra and never seen this QueryProcessor, you saved me long time :)

Comment: If you want to execute in sync then just remove the thread portion